# How do I check if $data = file_get_contents("php://stdin") is empty?

Tags: php

How do I check if

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
```

is empty, like for when one is supposed to pass a parameter but does not.

---

I have a file `test_cmd.php` :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

   $data = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
   echo $data;
```

When I run

```
$ ls -l | test_cmd.php
```

I get

```
total 36
drwxrwxr-x  3 username username 4096 Jan 20 11:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x 16 username username 4096 Jan 19 23:49 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username 4299 Jan 19 13:06 index.php
-rwxrwxr-x  1 username username 2619 Jan 20 12:58 test_cmd*
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username 3022 Jan 19 10:18 file1.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username 3022 Jan 19 10:18 file2.php
```

However when I run :

```
$ test_cmd.php
```

the console waits for text input, which I do not want to. I wanted to show the `Usage` help.

How do I correct this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `posix_isatty`:

```
if (posix_isatty(STDIN))
{
    die("Please don't run me interactively!");
}
else
{
    echo file_get_contents('php://stdin');
}
```

Comment: A quick test seems to work. I shall test it fully in a while.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if($filecontent = file_get_contents("php://stdin") !== false)
{
   // do stuff here
}
```